# The book "Opera De Cribro" by John Friedlander and Henryk Iwaniec

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

John Friedlander and  Henryk Iwaniec wrote a book  *[Opera De Cribro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849700)*. 
How about this book? What's the meaning of its title?  A number theory book with such a title seems odd.

p.s.  I have no way to buy this book or borrow a copy at the moment, so I want to learn some information about  it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [MAA website](http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/opera-de-cribro):

"The book’s title is Latin and may be translated freely as “Sieve Theory: The Musical.” While the musical jokes and puns may not have you tapping your toes to the music of the primes, the book is a chatty and relatively painless way to get up to date on sieve theory. Our understanding of sieves has improved greatly over the past 20 or 30 years, in large part due to the efforts of this book’s two authors, and proofs that used to take many pages in an almost incomprehensible notation can now be done cleanly in one page..."

Edit:
[You can also see quite a few pages from the book on Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0821849700)

Edit2:
Nobody seems to have picked up on the outrageous pun in the MAA reviewer's free translation ...